# Failed to load resource 403 Forbidden OneSignalSDKWorker.js and OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js

Tags: javascript, apache, onesignal

Getting a 403 error when using the `OneSignalSDKWorker.js` and `OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js`

**error** 
`403 Failed to load resource`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I changed the permissions of the uploaded file to chmod 755 `-rwxrwxr-x`.